# When use UIImage(named:"") and Bundle.main.path(forResource:) compositing images, why is the performance very different?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics

I need to combine two images into one, one of which is used as the background. The method when I use

```
let a = UIImage(named: "234")
let b = UIImage(named: "720")

let aRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
let bRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: backgroundImg.size.width, height: backgroundImg.size.height)

  ...
  let render = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bRect)
  let result = render.image { renderContext in
      backgroundImg.draw(in: bRect)
      image.draw(in: aRect)
  }
  return result
```

It took 2ms.

but when i use

```
let aPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "234@3x", ofType: "png")
let bPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "720@3x", ofType: "png")

let a = UIImage(contentsOfFile: aPath!)
let b = UIImage(contentsOfFile: bPath!)

  ...
  let render = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bRect)
  let result = render.image { renderContext in
      backgroundImg.draw(in: bRect)
      image.draw(in: aRect)
  }
  return result
```

It took 20ms,What led to a 10 fold increase in time?

My puzzle is that both methods load two images of a b into memory before image combine. But why is there such a difference in the process of image combine?

Code like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk2gI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is not the image compositing that takes longer. It is the file loading. In the first code, the images are cached in memory, so they take zero time to load after the first time. In the second code, the images are not cached so they have to be read from disk every time, which is slow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But you may have misunderstood my code. My code records the images into memory before the two images start to compose. I think the images of the two methods are in memory when they execute the composition method.In the above question, I added a picture. You can click to view it.